# req.user is undefined when I call app.post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to post information from a form to my express/Nodejs server. User is logged in and when I call `app.get('/api/stripe', async (req, res) => {` I am able to console.log the req.user with the correct user info. In order to pass the form data I am using `app.post('/api/stripe', async (req, res) => {` but when I use this method I get req.user is undefined.

My server client communication is managed with a passport session.

here is req from req.get (user is near bottom)

```
 GET /api/stripe/2 404 51.296 ms - 151

[0]access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJIdWJjYXAiLCJzdWIiOiI1ZmNmZTIwNjE2OGI5ZTRmZjAyNDkxOTEiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDc5ODA3MjEsImV4cCI6NDE5OTk4MDcyMX0.ReBH46wWlWDdKIKJRoF8p25LZNABfOFfGefDxVD5_lQ'
[0]   },
[0]   rawHeaders: [
[0]     'Host',
[0]     'localhost:3500',
[0]     'Connection',
[0]     'keep-alive',
[0]     'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests',
[0]     '1',
[0]     'User-Agent',
[0]     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
[0]     'Accept',
[0]     'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
[0]     'Purpose',
[0]     'prefetch',
[0]     'Sec-Fetch-Site',
[0]     'none',
[0]     'Sec-Fetch-Mode',
[0]     'navigate',
[0]     'Sec-Fetch-User',
[0]     '?1',
[0]     'Sec-Fetch-Dest',
[0]     'document',
[0]     'Accept-Encoding',
[0]     'gzip, deflate, br',
[0]     'Accept-Language',
[0]     'en-US,en;q=0.9',
[0]     'Cookie',
[0]     '_ga=GA1.1.1464203055.1605117764; user=%7B%22credits%22%3A0%2C%22plan%22%3A1%2C%22verified%22%3Afalse%2C%22_id%22%3A%225fcfe206168b9e4ff0249191%22%2C%22googleId%22%3A%22109475485380731334208%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22jaymaynard84%40gmail.com%22%2C%22profilePic%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2Fa-%2FAOh14Ghk_7fDTocUEuj6YIQVMUbgLdInjNeXPoJ2uU8GjA%3Ds96-c%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22%242a%2410%24L7c8AdTjNRMC.duLj%2FOeceUH6PonrllANjsKH6a4OwOcXW4LRwN8O%22%2C%22date%22%3A%222020-12-08T20%3A28%3A54.060Z%22%2C%22__v%22%3A0%7D; express:sess=eyJwYXNzcG9ydCI6eyJ1c2VyIjoiNWZjZmUyMDYxNjhiOWU0ZmYwMjQ5MTkxIn19; express:sess.sig=_-uz0y94SOq3hrEKFx5OspsfMSY; access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJIdWJjYXAiLCJzdWIiOiI1ZmNmZTIwNjE2OGI5ZTRmZjAyNDkxOTEiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDc5ODA3MjEsImV4cCI6NDE5OTk4MDcyMX0.ReBH46wWlWDdKIKJRoF8p25LZNABfOFfGefDxVD5_lQ'
[0]   ],

[0]   },
[0]   sessionOptions: {},
[0]   sessionKey: 'express:sess',
[0]   session: [Getter/Setter],
[0]   _passport: {
[0]     instance: Authenticator {
[0]       _key: 'passport',
[0]       _strategies: [Object],
[0]       _serializers: [Array],
[0]       _deserializers: [Array],
[0]       _infoTransformers: [],
[0]       _framework: [Object],
[0]       _userProperty: 'user',
[0]       _sm: [SessionManager],
[0]       Authenticator: [Function: Authenticator],
[0]       Passport: [Function: Authenticator],
[0]       Strategy: [Function],
[0]       strategies: [Object]
[0]     },
[0]     session: { user: '5fcfe206168b9e4ff0249191' }
[0]   },
[0]   user: {
[0]     credits: 0,
[0]     plan: 2,
[0]     verified: false,
[0]     _id: 5fcfe2249191,
[0]     googleId: '109475485380731334208',
[0]     email: 'jaymaynard84@gmail.com',
[0]     profilePic: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Ghk_7fDTocUEuj6YIQVMUbgLdInjNeXPoJ2uU8GjA=s96-c',
[0]     password: '$2a$10$L7c8AdTjNRMC.duLj/OeceUH6PonrllANjsKH6a4OwOcXW4LRwN8O',
[0]     date: 2020-12-08T20:28:54.060Z,
[0]     __v: 0,
[0]     stripeId: 'cus_IkAE7t'
[0]   },
[0]   route: Route {
[0]     path: '/api/stripe',
[0]     stack: [ [Layer] ],
[0]     methods: { get: true }
[0]   },
[0]   [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[0]   [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
[0] }
```

here is req from app.post

```
] OPTIONS /api/stripe 204 1.042 ms - 0
[0]   httpVersionMajor: 1,
[0]   httpVersionMinor: 1,
[0]   httpVersion: '1.1',
[0]   complete: true,
[0]   headers: {
[0]     host: 'localhost:3500',
[0]     connection: 'keep-alive',
[0]     'content-length': '151',
[0]     accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
[0]     authorization: 'token eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiI1ZmNhYjRjNTkzNDM0ZTUzZTA5MDVmM2IiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDcxMjAwNzB9.zV5bA_d0qZGSrUBqZ6mLBjlsRR-xDlquzKiBenFXbvU',
[0]     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
[0]     'x-custom-header': 'Hubcap',
[0]     'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
[0]     origin: 'http://localhost:3006',
[0]     'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
[0]     'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
[0]     'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
[0]     referer: 'http://localhost:3006/',
[0]     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
[0]     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
[0]   },
[0]   _body: true,
[0]   length: undefined,
[0]   sessionCookies: Cookies {
[0]     secure: undefined,
[0]     request: [Circular *2],
[0]     response: <ref *3> ServerResponse {
[0]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[0]       _eventsCount: 2,
[0]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[0]       outputData: [],
[0]       outputSize: 0,
[0]       writable: true,
[0]       destroyed: false,
[0]       _last: false,
[0]       chunkedEncoding: false,
[0]       shouldKeepAlive: true,
[0]       _defaultKeepAlive: true,
[0]       useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
[0]       sendDate: true,
[0]       _removedConnection: false,
[0]       _removedContLen: false,
[0]       _removedTE: false,
[0]       _contentLength: null,
[0]       _hasBody: true,
[0]       _trailer: '',
[0]       finished: false,
[0]       _headerSent: false,
[0]       socket: [Socket],
[0]       _header: null,
[0]       _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
[0]       _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
[0]       _sent100: false,
[0]       _expect_continue: false,
[0]       req: [Circular *2],
[0]       locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
[0]       _startAt: undefined,
[0]       _startTime: undefined,
[0]       writeHead: [Function: writeHead],
[0]       __onFinished: [Function],
[0]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[0]       [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
[0]       [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
[0]       [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
[0]     },
[0]     keys: Keygrip {
[0]       sign: [Function (anonymous)],
[0]       verify: [Function (anonymous)],
[0]       index: [Function (anonymous)]
[0]     }
[0]   },
[0]   sessionOptions: {},
[0]   sessionKey: 'express:sess',
[0]   session: [Getter/Setter],
[0]   _passport: {
[0]     instance: Authenticator {
[0]       _key: 'passport',
[0]       _strategies: [Object],
[0]       _serializers: [Array],
[0]       _deserializers: [Array],
[0]       _infoTransformers: [],
[0]       _framework: [Object],
[0]       _userProperty: 'user',
[0]       _sm: [SessionManager],
[0]       Authenticator: [Function: Authenticator],
[0]       Passport: [Function: Authenticator],
[0]       Strategy: [Function],
[0]       strategies: [Object]
[0]     }
[0]   },
[0]   route: Route {
[0]     path: '/api/stripe',
[0]     stack: [ [Layer] ],
[0]     methods: { post: true }
[0]   },
[0]   [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[0]   [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
[0] }
```

server.js

```
'''
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [keys.cookieKey],
    domain: 'localhost',
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // console.log(req.session);
  // console.log(req.cookie);
  next();
});
//app.use(require('./middlewares/JWT'));

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);

require('./routes/billingRoutes')(app);
```

authRoutes

```
  //google
  app.get(
    '/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
      scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    })
  );

  app.get(
    '/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function (req, res) {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const { _id } = req.user;
        const t = token.signToken(_id);
        // console.log(req.user.plan);
        res.cookie('access_token', t, { httpOnly: true });
        if (req.user.plan == 1) {
          res.redirect(keys.redirectDomainTrial);
        } else {
          res.redirect(keys.redirectDomain);
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

passport.js

```
/** @format */

const passport = require('passport');
require('passport-oauth2');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const generator = require('generate-password');

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

//google
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
      proxy: true,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({
        // googleId: profile.id,
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
      });
      if (existingUser) {
        if (existingUser.googleId) {
          return done(null, existingUser);
        } else if (existingUser.facebookId) {
          return done(null, existingUser);
        } else if (existingUser.twitterId) {
          return done(null, existingUser);
        } else {
          return done(null, existingUser);
        }
      } else {
        const user = await new User({
          googleId: profile.id,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          profilePic: profile.photos[0].value,
          password: generator.generate({ length: 10, numbers: true }),
        }).save();

        // try {
        //   let newuser = { email: user.email, password: user.password };
        //   let token = jwt.sign({ userid: newuser.id }, keys.cookieKey);
        //   res.json({ token });
        // } catch (e) {
        //   console.log(e);
        // }
        done(null, user);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Here is the route (billingroutes)

```
  app.post('/api/stripe', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
    const plan = await stripe.plans.retrieve('price_1HfAZGGFN31Q4RRjSrFXnGgD');
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log(req.user);
    console.log(req.body);
    if (req.user.stripeId) {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(req.user.stripeId);
    } else {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.user.email,
        description: 'Subscribing to Personal Plan Monthly Subscription',
      });
      req.user.stripeId = customer.id;
      const user = await req.user.save();
    }
    req.user.plan = 2;
    const user = await req.user.save();
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: req.user.stripeId,
      items: [{ price: 'price_1HfAZGGFN31Q4RRjSrFXnGgD' }],
    });
```

middleware
requirelogin.js

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  // console.log(req.session, 'SESSION')
  // console.log(req.cookie)
  if (!req.user) {
    return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You must log in!' });
  }
  next();
};
```

Comment: Where have you included your passport middleware?

Comment: I added a few more relevant files to the question. The route I'm calling is in billingroutes.js and I have not referenced passport here. I thought since the session was started when the user logged in that I didn't have to? I included part of my passport.js file and my authRoutes.js file where I keep routes used for user oauth.

Comment: added in a requireLogin middleware, but it is giving a 401 error